# Why can't we extend enumeration in Protocol's Extension?

Tags: swift, protocols, enumeration

I met the Error like below.
Why can't we extend enumeration in Protocol's Extension?
I can't sleep until it's solved.
Thanks.

```swift
protocol ABC { }

extension ABC { 
    enum Wow {      //Error: Type 'Wow' cannot be nested in protocol extension of 'ABC'
        case one
        case two
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gquy.png)

Comment: You can't declare nested types in protocols, so what makes you think that you can do that in protocol extensions?

Comment: It's not only the enum, you shouldn't either be able to define a struct/class nested inside the protocol. See the allowed nested: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/NestedTypes.html

Comment: Thanks for answers. Protocol extension can provide default implementation, so I thought it can define nested type like class/struct. I understood that Protocol can't require nested type and can't implement it even in extension